# How can I specify the sequence of running nested web components constructors?

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I created two web-components and nested one of them into the other.
Both of them have its `constructor`. The problem that I have is that, I have no control on running the sequence of the `constructor`s.
Is there any way which I can set this out?

Here's my code:

**child web component:**

```
(function () {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `<div>WC1</div>`;

    class WC1Component extends HTMLElement {

        constructor() {
            super();
            console.log('WC1: constructor()');

            var me = this;

            me._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
            me._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            console.log('WC1: connectedCallback');
        }

        test() {
            console.log('test:wc1');
        }

    }

    window.customElements.define('wc-one', WC1Component);

}());
```

**parent web component:**

```
(function () {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
    <wc-one id="wc1"></wc-one>
    <div>WC2</div>
    `;

    class WC2Component extends HTMLElement {

        constructor() {
            super();
            console.log('WC2: constructor()');

            var me = this;

            me._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
            me._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
            me._wc1 = me._shadowRoot.querySelector('#wc1');
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            console.log('WC2: connectedCallback');
            this._wc1.test(); // <-- Error: test is undefined!
        }


    }

    window.customElements.define('wc-two', WC2Component);

}());
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test Web Component</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="wc1.js"></script>
    <script src="wc2.js"></script>

    <wc-two></wc-two>
    <script>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result:

```
WC2: constructor()
WC2: connectedCallback

Uncaught TypeError: this._wc1.test is not a function

WC1: constructor()
WC1: connectedCallback
```

Comment: you can use "async", "defer" for script tag. For example, you want to load wc1.js before wc2.js: <script async src="wc1.js"></script>, <script defer src="wc2.js"></script>. But it's not the solution for many js files. You can take a look at "gulp" or "webpack" will help you manage your js files better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do have control on the running sequence of the constructors.

Since `<wc-one>` is created by `<wc-two>` the WC2 constructor will always be called before WC1.

The error is due to the fact that when you try invoke it, the inner component (WC1) is not yet added to the DOM.

You could listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to be sure element is OK, or the `load` event on `window`, or implement the `window.onload` handler. @elanz-nasiri is aslo working.

`DOMContentLoaded` will be fired first.

There're alternate solution but they are more difficult to implement.

```js
window.customElements.define('wc-one', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' }).innerHTML = `<div>WC1</div>`
    }
    test(source) {   
        console.log('test:wc1', source)
    }
} )

window.customElements.define('wc-two', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' })
        this._shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<wc-one id="wc1"></wc-one><div>WC2</div>`
        this._wc1 = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('#wc1');
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout( ()=>this._wc1.test('setTimout') )            
        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', ()=>this._wc1.test('DOMContentLoaded') )
        window.onload = ()=>this._wc1.test('window.onload')
        window.addEventListener( 'load', ()=>this._wc1.test('load') )
    }
} )
```

```html
<wc-two></wc-two>
```

Comment: @tahereh thank you for the accepted answer, you can upvote if it helped :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this._wc1.test();
});
```

in connectedCallback

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control when a constructor is called then you need to call it. Do not allow the HTML parser to do it for you. The problem with allowing the HTML parser to do it is that you do not know *when* the component will be upgraded.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<div>WC1</div>`;

class WC1Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('WC1: constructor()');

    this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('WC1: connectedCallback');
  }

  test() {
    console.log('test:wc1');
  }
}

window.customElements.define('wc-one', WC1Component);

//<wc-one id="wc1"></wc-one>
//<div>WC2</div>

class WC2Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('WC2: constructor()');
    let wc1 = document.createElement('wc-one');
    wc1.id = 'wc1';

    this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
    this._wc1 = wc1;
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(wc1);
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = 'WC2';
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(div);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('WC2: connectedCallback');
    this._wc1.test();
  }
}

window.customElements.define('wc-two', WC2Component);
```

```html
<wc-two></wc-two>
```

All I am doing is causing the constructor for `wc-one` to execute by calling `document.createElement('wc-one')` and then I add that into the component. This forces the object to exist before I attempt to use its `test` function.

Also, you do not need to save off the return value of `this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });` since it is already available as `this.shadowRoot`.

You also do not need to save off `this` as `me`.